# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Not Displaying

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a bootstrap carousel to my HTML page.

I got the below code from the Bootstrap website [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#example):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

                <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

                    <title>Hello, world!</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

                    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="gsi.png" alt="First slide">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="gsi.png" alt="Second slide">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="gsi.png" alt="Third slide">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"/>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"/>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
                                <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
                                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
                                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
                                <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
                            </body>
                        </html>
```

The first image is loading as you can see below, & the carousel moves onto the next image afterwards, but it isn't being rendered correctly.

[image]

Can someone please tell me why the Bootstrap carousel isn't loading successfully?

Comment: I've edited my answer and created a working example based on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, there are tags which are always self-closed.
For example, `<hr>Some content here</hr>` does not make any sense. In the same way, there are tags which cannot be self-closed. `<script>` tag is one of them.

That means every `<script>` tag has to be paired with closing `</script>` tag.

so for you scripts try:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Full working example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/200" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried your changes but there is no change unfortunately

Comment: Try the snippet I've just inserted.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

   <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/colorful-light-bokeh-background-festive-concept_9693-1027.jpg" alt="First slide">
         </div>
         <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/colorful-light-bokeh-background-festive-concept_9693-1027.jpg" alt="Second slide">
         </div>
         <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/colorful-light-bokeh-background-festive-concept_9693-1027.jpg" alt="Third slide">
         </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
         <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
         <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
   </div>

   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
   <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am still experiencing the same issue. I have added a screenshot above to show what is happening

Comment: @user9847788 If you look at the snippet, it works fine, so if it doesn't, that means it hasn't been copied properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the scripts in the head tag

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/150" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/150" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/150" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```